# Drawing features with specific dimensions in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, length, dimensions

I am having some issues drawing transect lines in ArcGIS. I need to create some lines that have specific lengths (20m and 30m). My Map units are set to 'meters' and coordinate system is NAD UTM 10. When I hit CTRL+L and enter the desired  line length the line is far too long! I can verify this by using the measure/ruler tool.

I also need to draw some square polygons... and am having the same issue!

What is going on?

Comment: Is your data in geographic or unknown coordinates? The Ctrl + L (constrain to length) tool works best if both the map and the data is in the same projected coordinate system.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m700000058000000

Comment: Yes, I have been using CTRL + L for lines and L/W commands for  rectangular polygons. Both both the features and Data Frames are NAD UTM 10. I was doing something similar a few months back and it worked flawlessly. Very Frustrating. I just tried again ... attempted to draw a square exactly 5 x 5 m but arcgis drew one that was 40 x 40 m.

Comment: ...I am using 10.3

Comment: Figured it out! For some reason under Editor > Options > Units > 'Ground to Grid Correction' was checked and 'Direction Offset' and 'Distance Factor' were set to '4 decimal degrees' and '4' respectively. I have no idea why but I'm glad that was resolved.